# Angular CLI 7 New Project Fails due to CircularJSON

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

Just reinstalled Angular CLI to version 7.1.1. When running `ng new project-name`, the following error occurs:

`npm WARN deprecated circular-json@0.5.9: CircularJSON is in maintenance only, flatted is its successor.`
`npm ERR! code ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END`
`npm ERR! write after end`
`npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:`
`npm ERR! C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-12-04T20_40_23_399Z-debug.log`
`Package install failed, see above.`

When changing into the project directory, the new Angular application cannot be served. How can this be repaired?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be looking at the error details.

```
npm WARN deprecated circular-json@0.5.9: CircularJSON is in maintenance 
only, flatted is its successor.
```

According to it circular-json@0.5.9 is deprecated. You should use [**flatted**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flatted). A super light (0.5K) and fast circular JSON parser, directly from the creator of CircularJSON. The future of CircularJSON is called flatted.

> Smaller, faster, and able to produce on average a reduced output too, **flatted** is the new, bloatless, ESM and CJS compatible, circular JSON parser.

install it using: `npm i flatted`

Comment: I installed "flatted" globally. That is the only difference.

Comment: installing it globally , will work ?? or not to install globally @crayden

Comment: i would prefer to keep it  at project level since it's needed by the project.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried accepted answer's solution but nothing happened.

Thus after some search I found a solution for me. May be it could help someone else

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Comment: Solved my problem of circular json like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: First upgrade angular/cli using this command `npm upgrade -g @angular/cli`

Step 2: After that restart your PC

Step 3: After that create new project `ng new my-app`

It should work.

Comment: Restarting the PC is definitely a huge overkill. Surely not necessary.

Comment: We are not installing package, we are upgrading package, so some time it is necessary